# Only show link if conditional equals true

Tags: php, if-statement

I want the link to appear only when `$data['block']` equals to 1, 3 or 4. Not if it equals to 2 or 5.

```
<td style="font-size:18px;color:#f0cb01;">
    <a href="kickcodes.php?id='.$data["block"].'">Reason Codes</a>
</td>
```

EDIT

```
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

echo '
<tr style="background-color:#576c11;">
    <td style="font-size:18px; color:#f0cb01;">'.$data["keyword"].'</td>
    <td style="font-size:18px;color:#f0cb01;">'.$data["block"].'</td>
    <td style="font-size:18px;color:#f0cb01;">'.$data["phone"].'</td>
    <td style="font-size:18px;color:#f0cb01;">'.$data["Reason"].'</td>
    <td style="font-size:18px;color:#f0cb01;"><a href="kickcodes.php?id='.$data  ["block"].'">Kickcodes</a></td>'

    echo '<td style="font-size:18px;color:#f0cb01;">'; 
if( $data['block'] == 1 || $data['block'] == 3 || $data['block'] == 4)  
{ 
echo '<a href="kickcodes.php?id='.$data["block"].'">Reason Codes</a>'; 
} else  
{ 
echo '<span>Reason Codes</span>'; // Or echo nothing 
} 
echo '</td>';
```

Comment: What if `$data['block']` is 2 or 5? An empty `td` only ? Or no `td` at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the conditions you want the link to occur within an `if` statement:

```
echo '<td style="font-size:18px;color:#f0cb01;">';
if( $data['block'] == 1 || $data['block'] == 3 || $data['block'] == 4) 
{
    echo '<a href="kickcodes.php?id='.$data["block"].'">Reason Codes</a>';
} else 
{
    echo '<span>Reason Codes</span>'; // Or echo nothing
}
echo '</td>';
```

It wouldn't make sense in a table to omit a `<td>` tag, which is why I placed it outside of the `if` statement.

```
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

echo '
<tr style="background-color:#576c11;">
    <td style="font-size:18px; color:#f0cb01;">'.$data["keyword"].'</td>
    <td style="font-size:18px;color:#f0cb01;">'.$data["block"].'</td>
    <td style="font-size:18px;color:#f0cb01;">'.$data["phone"].'</td>
    <td style="font-size:18px;color:#f0cb01;">'.$data["Reason"].'</td>
    <td style="font-size:18px;color:#f0cb01;"><a href="kickcodes.php?id='.$data  ["block"].'">Kickcodes</a></td>';

    echo '<td style="font-size:18px;color:#f0cb01;">'; 
    if( $data['block'] == 1 || $data['block'] == 3 || $data['block'] == 4)  
    { 
        echo '<a href="kickcodes.php?id='.$data["block"].'">Reason Codes</a>';     
    } 
    else  
    { 
       echo '<span>Reason Codes</span>'; // Or echo nothing 
    } 
    echo '</td>';
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO, expecting ',' or ';' in /var/www/database.php on line 52

Comment: sorry i put that in your answer... let me fix that

Answer (score 3):

This will work:

```
<td style="font-size:18px;color:#f0cb01;">
 <?php if (in_array($data["block"], array(1,3,4)){?>
    <a href="kickcodes.php?id='.$data["block"].'">Reason Codes</a>
<?php}?>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 echo '<td style="font-size:18px;color:#f0cb01;">';
 if ($data['block'] == 1 || $data['block'] == 3 || $data['block'] == 4) {
    echo '<a href="kickcodes.php?id='.$data["block"].'">Reason Codes</a>';
 }
 echo '</td>';
```

if you are using words instead of numbers you can do like :

```
echo '<td style="font-size:18px;color:#f0cb01;">';

if ($data['block'] == 'block 1' || $data['block'] == 'block 3' || $data['block'] == 'block 4') {
  echo '<a href="kickcodes.php?id='.$data["block"].'">Reason Codes</a>';
}
echo '</td>';
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I need to make a correction. I almost have this working.. The issue is instead of using just the number it is actually a word + number

Comment: how would i make this work? if ($data['block'] == block 1 || $data['block'] == block 3 || $data['block'] == block 4) {

Comment: @DaveMorin 'wrap' your `word + number` in quotes, i.e. `$data['block'] == 'block 1'` and the same for the other ones.

Comment: @DaveMorin Like Havelock said you should do like  if ($data['block'] == 'block 1' || $data['block'] == 'block 3' || $data['block'] == 'block 4') { //rest of code here}